# Linear Regulator: MOSFET vs BJT

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, bjt, control, linear-regulator

Currently I am doing a project on a voltage regulator. Can you tell me some advantages of MOSFETs over BJT? Apart from a higher power loss, I can not find much. In control engineering it is much more difficult to deal with them. Would be great if you could tell me a few.

Comment: Please elaborate on 'much more difficult to deal with them'. To me, controlling a series-pass MOSFET gate voltage is trivially easy with an op-amp.

Comment: to get stability with pmos is not as easy as it sounds. They start oscillating very easy.

Comment: *Anything* with a feedback loop can oscillate very easily. Also please update your question if you specifically want to consider PMOS / PNP.

Comment: _"Can you tell me some advantages of MOSFETs over BJT? Apart from a higher power loss ..."_ - It depends on your parts and the required current, but FETs tend to have a _lower_ power loss than BTJs.

Answer (score 7):

In a linear regulator, switching speed isn't a consideration.  However, BJT base current can be.  There's no steady-state gate current in a MOSFET so a MOSFET can be lower loss.

Also, a MOSFET in the on state looks resistive, so the dropout voltage can be very small at low currents.  A BJT will saturate and may lead to higher dropout voltage at low currents.

At higher currents a BJT can suffer from low current gain.

All of these things can be mitigated by proper design, but they are definitely considerations when choosing a pass element.

Comment: Just to add one downside of MOSFETS, if you want to use an N-Channel you have to have a way to bring the gate higher that the input voltage, and if you use a P-FET the area will be significantly larger than an N-FET or BJT for similar performance.

Comment: that's true, so far I have not managed a pmos regulator to stabilize. They start pretty quickly oscillate at higher loads, despite snubber etc.

Comment: Sounds like you don't use appropriate compensation - BTW snubbers are used for suppressing high-frequency switching noise, not in regulator control loops. There's nothing inherently wrong with using a MOSFET as a regulator.

Answer (score 3):

The most common MOSFETs these days are power MOSFETs.The on resistance of the lower voltage devices should mean less voltage wasted when gate drive is designed properly. On the face of it they will be better than BJTs.

Now there is a real catch. As the power MOSFET heats up which is bound to happen in high power linear service the gate source threshold voltage falls tending to increase drain current for a given gate source volts. This junction heating will increase on resistance which tends to make drain current fall.

The real Power MOSFETs consists of millions of paralleled tiny FETs called cells. The thermal impedance of the individual cells will be different when say considering the center or say the edge. The total current is managed by your circuit but the current sharing of the cells is not. What if one cell got a little hotter and the falling gate source threshold volts increased cell current to a much greater extent than increasing on resistance? In other words if you dont take steps the device could blow due to localized hot spots. This could occur well below Average Tj max. This potential problem is worse at high volts and high powers.

Using linear FETs will fix this at extra cost and increased on resistance. Using early gen old devices is helpful but results in more on resistance. Series connection is more complex and does work at a on resistance penalty. Deliberately using high volt devices on a low volt job is helpful at a penalty of cost and on resistance.

Derating the device more than normal would help but it is not clear how much by. This potential current crowding hot spot mechanism sounds a bit like second breakdown in BJTs, but the BJTs manufacturers were much more clear about this.

Comment: It doesn't matter if FET is "linear" or "power" MOSFET, as far as you are within SOA, right? If your are using power MOSFET, and you are within SOA, you can use it even for linear operation.

Comment: I think power MOSFET don't specify an SOA graph so it's a lot harder to tell if you're within limits or not since they aren't expected to be used that way.

Comment: @DKNguyen I've looked into datasheets of MOSFETs I have on hand right now, and they ALL have SOA specified. IRF540N, IRF640N, IRFP150N, IRFP250N, IRLML2803PbF. So I don't see your comment to be valid.

Comment: @Chupacabras I just checked IRF and other manufacturers. It's not always listed but it is listed it a lot more frequently than I thought. I must just tune it out since I don't use any old MOSFET in linear mode.

Comment: @DKNguyen I have just checked random power MOSFETs from several manufacturers and they ALL have SOA specified. Vishay SiHA22N60EF, ON Semi NTHL050N65S3HF, ST STF26N60DM6. So, I don't see even your second statement to be valid.

Comment: @DKNguyen Just curious, what "linear MOSFETs" are you using?

Comment: @Chupacabras The linear MOSFETs I've used are from IXYS. Things like DMHC3025LSD, DMP4015SPSQ and IRF7317 don't have SOA listed, but curiously enough, the IRF8313 does so I'm not sure what the difference is there. You do find power MOSFETs without SOA listed but I would expect every linear MOSFET to  have SOA  because they are useless without it (like if  power MOS had no RDson).

Comment: @DKNguyen DMHC3025LSD and IRF7317 are in SO-8 package. So there is no point to show SOA. SO-8 package is absolutely unsuitable to think about use in linear mode.

Comment: @Chupacabras The IRF8313 is also SO8 and does have SOA listed, as do the IRLML24023/2502/6302/6402 which are in SOT23 so I don't think packaging is the common delineator here.

Comment: @DKNguyen When you pick probably any MOSFET in TO-220 or TO-247 package there will be SOA specified.

Comment: @Chupacabras Yes, that does seem to be the case where any large package obviously intended to heatsink has SOA listed. With smaller packages it starts to become hit or miss.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of power mosfets are intended for switching application, so makers very rarely specify DC SOA curve. All the transistors, cited above, are not guarantied for DC operation. The only type, suitable for linear (DC) application is lateral (LDMOS) types. These are used for high end sound amplifiers and as RF power transistors, and they have positive Vth tempco at useful range of drain current. All of them are very, very expensive!
Using vertical (normal) mosfet as power pass element, at more than 5-15V dropout and 10-5A is not reliable.
MOSFETS have only two advantages: zero gate current, and almost always Tj=175*C which is very favorable for heat sinking. Disadvantage is high threshold, which gives high dropout in a follower configuration without using additional voltage source for control circuit.
BJTs are always specified for DC SOA, have low Vbe, but plastic packaged types have low Tj of 150*C. Metal ones (TO-3) have Tj=200*C, but are rare and rare in recent years, and very expensive (those with verified origin).

Comment: The question is specifically about linear *voltage regulators* so much of what you are arguing here is of only limited relevance.  Linear voltage regulators themselves are only reasonable choices at fairly low currents, especially given the performance and price point of modern switchers.  And most modern low dropout forms *do* in fact use FETs as the main power element...