# Advantages BJT over MOSFET?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt

There exists this qeustion about MOSFET advantages over BJT's [Linear Regulator: MOSFET vs BJT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124510)

So my question is: What advantages do BJT's have over MOSFETS ?

So far I have these advantages:

- They operate better under high load than MOSFETS
- They operate better with higher frequencies than MOSFETS

What else did I miss ?

Comment: It might be more relevant to compare a BLT to a Bolgna sandwich considering the millions of different varieties of transistors , circuits , topography , substrates and doping.  For LDO's MOSFETs have lower bias current, lower dropout from lower RdsOn , and smaller packages but require constraints on Cap ESR for stable regulation.

Comment: What is better .. a Nail or a Screw.. They both can be used for the same thing, but are very different. Which is better when is really application dependent. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: See: https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/static/companion.websites/9780199339136/Appendices/Appendix_G.pdf

Comment: BJT's non-saturation region is good for analog amplification, BJTs have (potentially) a lower "on voltage" than VGSth, BJTs are cheaper and less static-sensitive.

Comment: @Trevor I can see your point but there has to be something that the BJT can do that MOSFET's cant do, much like a nail can be hammered in with any solid object while a screw required "specialized equipment"

Comment: For small signal switching applications, BJT's are cheaper than MOSFET's. When purchased in high volume, a 2N3904 in SOT-23 package is around US$ 0.0075, but a BSS138 MOSFET is more than US$ 0.01. There are also a variety of simple linear circuits that won't work right with MOSFET's. Some LED driver circuits, for example. BJT's are more likely to be matched to each other than MOSFET's. So they are better for current mirrors and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BJT generally offers more gain and higher fidelity in the linear region than FET

Answer (score 1):

They can be considerably less expensive for equivalent functionality.

For higher voltages, BJTs can be a better choice, for example the MPSA42/MMBTA42 for switching 100s of volts at low current. Many CCFL lamps use BJTs (eg. MJE13003) for that reason.